# Internet explorer doesn't see laravel 5.1 cookies

Tags: php, internet-explorer, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.1

Framework: Laravel 5.1

Problem browsers: All versions of IE (inc. Edge)

Problem: When posting a form a cookie is set when the user is send back after submitting the form.

```
return Response::make($view)->withCookie(cookie('parameters', json_encode($request->except(['_token']))))
```

This works in ALL browsers, except of course **Internet explorer** (why does this browser still exists?!)

In internet explorer i get an empty array when i dump the cookie. I've tried a lot. I'm **not using iframes,** but i did try to use P3P headers without success, i've set IE to the lowest security level possible, also without success. I'm not using suddomains or underscores in the cookiename. I tried it on multiple domains without success, i tried it on apache, nginx, and in my local env. (homestead) it also does not work.

It looks like the cookie isn't set (while in all other browsers it is being set). Unfortunately IE does not have an option or possible add-on to easily check al stored cookies (like all other browsers do). But i`m almost certain the cookie doesn't get stored. This is strange, because laravel's session cookies are stored.

I think i already spent a half a day on this, but cant find any solutions. If i would get payed for all the hours i spend on weird bugs with IE, i would be a very rich man. Will stop bashing IE now, but men, what a horrible browser.

edit: Other things i tried: Timezone checks, date checks, server time etc. All didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try renaming session cookie to a alpha numeric string. It's `laravel_session` which is causing problem in IE. I remember last month when I deployed my app with session cookie (`domain.com`) and I got similar token mismatch error in every browser due to `.` in session name.

I tried to Google and came up with this:

> Security patch MS01-055 prevents servers with improper name syntax
>   from setting cookies names. Domains that use cookies must use only
>   alphanumeric characters ("-" or ".") in the domain name and the server
>   name. Internet Explorer blocks cookies from a server if the server
>   name contains other characters, such as an underscore character ("_").
>
> Because ASP session state and session variables rely on cookies to
>   function, ASP cannot maintain session state between requests if
>   cookies cannot be set on the client.
>
> This issue can also be caused by an incorrect name syntax in a host
>   header.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316112

> Q5: IE won’t set a cookie when the hostname/domain contains an
>   underscore?
>
> A: Correct. Technically, an underscore (like this _ ) is not a DNS
>   character, and while Windows will let you use an underscore when
>   naming your machine, it warns you that doing so may cause problems.
>   One such problem is that WinINET blocks attempts to set cookies on
>   such domains. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316112/en-us

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx

Comment: Thanks for you answer and links. Unfortunately i`m already using a alpha numeric string as a cookie name. I tried different names. Cookie names like: 'test'  (as a session cookie)  still dont work in IE.